# Зачем так много типов исключений в .Net

Tags: c#, .net, исключения, framework, vb.net

В .Net мы имеем кучу разных типов исключений, но зачем?
В каком случае может понадобиться разработчику генерировать какой-либо определённый тип, а не например просто Exception?
Может ли это быть полезным на более высоких уровнях обработки исключений?

[image: Список некоторых исключений]

Comment: .Net не знаю, но это типично для любого языка, где есть исключения, полагаю. Представьте, что какие-то из исключений вам не важны (да хоть из 10 000 входных цифр попалась одна буква - это не страшно, и вы готовы продолжать работать в этом случае - тогда вы особо обработаете это исключение).

Comment: `на более высоких уровнях обработки исключений` в первый раз слышу о каких-то уровнях.

Comment: Приведу пример, пишем библиотеку - это будет первый уровень, далее используем методы библиотеки в другом месте кода, и это будет второй уровень, где так же возможна обработка исключений.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Правилом хорошего тона считается, что в каждом приложении должен быть набор специфических исключений предметной области.
В разработке через Catch ExceptionType проверяем и обрабатываем исключения относительно типа.
Так же в таком случае обработки добавляется Catch без типа, для которого обычно пишется блок отправки описания исключения в лог.
Считается, что после логирования нужно повторно кинуть этот Exception, чтобы он перешёл на следующий уровень, на котором его может ожидать обработка.

Exceptions typs помогают элегантно обрабатывать ошибки, и каким-то образом быстро скомпилировать код для CPU.

Comment: `каким-то образом быстро скомпилировать код для CPU` в этом месте я не понял, что вы имели в виду. Это гуглотранслейт чтоли? Дайте ссылку на исходный текст.

Comment: практические любая инструкция языка компилируется, обсуждаемая конструкция кода наиболее естественная для обработки исключений и компилируется эффективнее.

Comment: "инструкция" - это у процессора, она уже скомпилирована. "компилируется эффективнее" - чем что? Что вы понимаете под эффективностью? Скорость? Количество полученных байт инструкций в машинном коде? При чем тут это вообще?

Comment: Дайте угадаю, вы пишете не на русском языке, а используете переводчик, так? Если да, то он странно переводит, почти непонятно. С какого языка?

Comment: Да не, я думаю на Русском, великом и могучем) согласен, возможно вместо "инструкция" стоит использовать "конструкция", я имел в виду, что конструкция try|catch эффективнее компилируется (решает исключения) чем например If или case. С другой стороны инструкции могут быть, как в отношении процессора так и в отношении языка. Например каждый оператор в языке подразумевает инструкцию для компилятора.

Comment: Это вопрос не спорный. Зачем использовать странные слова вместо общепринятых терминов?

Comment: Холиварный вопрос не по теме, предлагаю удалить, и перейти в личку, если действительно интересно.

Answer (score 1):

Специфические исключения очень полезны.

Например, вы пишете парсер, который обращается к сайтам и получает информацию. Довольно типичной может быть (допустим) ситуация, когда из-за проблем с сайтом, или с нашим интернетом, или с прокси выскакивает `TimeoutException`. Имеет смысл обрабатывать это исключение отдельно, например, делая повторные попытки обратиться к сайту с тем же самым запросом. А вот если произошло какое-то другое исключение, то, наверное, тут уже проблемы побольше и просто так перезапрашивать сайт смысла нет, нужно его пропускать или делать что-то ещё.

Или, например, вы пишете калькулятор, и при этом не проверяете ввод (чтобы упростить код или ввод вы не можете контролировать, причины могут быть разные). Имеет смысл обработать отдельно исключение `DivideByZero` с сообщением пользователю, что "на ноль делить нельзя" и попросить его повторно ввести данные.

Таких примеров можно много придумать. Причём, уровней ловли таких исключений может быть несколько. Какие-то исключения имеет смысл ловить в самом низу, близко к коду, на котором они произошли, а какие-то на уровнях выше по логике. Например, если мы работаем с очередью задач на парсинг сайтов, то имеет смысл ловить какие-то исключения на уровне работы с очередью задач, чтобы, например, отложить задачу по скачке проблемного сайта на более позднее время.

Удобно делать работу с сущностями на каком-то одном уровне абстракции (а не размазывать её по разным уровням), а для этого нужно ловить соответствующие исключения именно на этом уровне. Исключения тем и удобны, что их не нужно передавать в явном виде через все уровни программы, как, например, аргументы методов, их можно кинуть в самом низу, а поймать на том уровне, на каком вам удобно будет их обработать.

Ну и не всегда находятся готовые исключения, соответствующие логике вашей программы, поэтому имеет смысл писать пользовательские исключения, чтобы можно было по такому же шаблону проектирования ловить разные исключения на разных уровнях программы. Писать свои исключения - это отдельный вид искусства и не всегда это бывает нужно, но это вполне применяется на практике и это удобно.